# Update form after editing any field value AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form in a modal window which adds new customers to the main page in a tabular format. This table has a edit button. I am loading same form with prefilled values in that modal form.

Now, I want to edit any field and update the same in the table on page.

Here is my code.

```js
var app = angular.module("formList", ['ngMessages']);

app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.formElements = [];
  $scope.editUser = false;
 // $scope.jdDate = "";
 var regexDate = /^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;
 // $scope.regex = regexDate;
 $scope.regex = '\\d+';
 $scope.dateCheck = function(user){
    var regexDate = '/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/';
    // alert('I am here');
   return regexDate.test(user.date);
 } 

 
  $scope.mobileValidator = function(user){

    //Mobile Number
      var mobileRegex = /^[789]\d{9}$/;
      if(mobileRegex.test(user.mobile)){
        $scope.mobileValid = false;
      }else{
        $scope.mobileValid = true;
       
      }

    };

  $scope.emailValidator = function(user){
      //Email 
      var emailRegex = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@justdial\.com$/i;

      if(emailRegex.test(user.email)){
        $scope.emailValid = false;
      }else{
        $scope.emailValid = true;
       
      }
  };

  $scope.altMobValidator = function(user){
      //Alternate Mobile no.
      var mobileRegex = /^[789]\d{9}$/;
      if(mobileRegex.test(user.altMobile)){
        $scope.altMobileValid = false;
      }else{
        $scope.altMobileValid = true;
       
      }
  };

   $scope.dobValidator = function(user){
      //Alternate Mobile no.
      var dobRegex = /^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;
      if(dobRegex.test(user.dob)){
        $scope.dobValid = false;
      }else{
        $scope.dobValid = true;
       
      }
  };

  $scope.pincodeValidator = function(user){
      //Alternate Mobile no.
      var pincodeRegex = /^([0-9]{6})$/;
      if(pincodeRegex.test(user.pincode)){
        $scope.pincodeValid = false;
      }else{
        $scope.pincodeValid = true;
       
      }
  };

      

 $scope.addCustomer =  function (user){

  // $scope.formElements = angular.copy(user);
   // angular.forEach(user, function(value, key){
   //   $scope.formElements.push(key + ': ' + value);
   // }) 
   $scope.formElements.push(
         {

          mobile: user.mobile, 
          name: user.firstName + user.lastName, 
          email: user.email,
          altMobile: user.altMobile,
          dob: user.dob, 
          gender: user.gender, 
          pincode: user.pincode, 
          address: user.address, 
          district: user.district, 
          state: user. state

        }
      );
   
   $scope.showResults = true;
  
 }

  $scope.edit = function(){
     $scope.editUser = true;
      // $scope.formElements = angular.copy(user);
  }

 $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.formElements);
  };

  $scope.delete = function(user, index) {
      $scope.formElements.splice(index, 1);
  }

  $scope.updateCustomer = function(user){

     //$scope.formElements = angular.copy(user);
$scope.formElements[index] = angular.copy(user); //UPDATED and worked but problem being that doesn't checks for null values. 
angular.forEach(angular.copy(user), function(value, key){
      if(value)
      {
         $scope.formElements[index].key = value;
      }

});

       
  }

 }]);

// app.directive('overwriteEmail', function() {
//   var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@justdial\.com$/i;

//   return {
//     require: 'ngModel',
//     restrict: '',
//     link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
//       // only apply the validator if ngModel is present and Angular has added the email validator
//       if (ctrl && ctrl.$validators.email) {

//         // this will overwrite the default Angular email validator
//         ctrl.$validators.email = function(modelValue) {
//           return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || EMAIL_REGEXP.test(modelValue);
//         };
//       }
//     }
//   };
// });
// app.directive('jdDate',function () {
//  return {
//   replace:true,
//   scope:{
//    jdModel:"="
//   },
//   template:"<input type='text' ng-model='abc' />",
//   link:function (scope) {

//    scope.jdModel = "123";
//   }
//  }
// })
app.directive('dateValidator', function() {
  var dateregex = /^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: '',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      // only apply the validator if ngModel is present and Angular has added the email validator
      if (ctrl && ctrl.$validators.elm) {

        ctrl.$validators.elm = function(modelValue) {
          return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || dateregex.test(modelValue);
        };
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
/* Welcome to Compass.
 * In this file you should write your main styles. (or centralize your imports)
 * Import this file using the following HTML or equivalent:
 * <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> */
/* line 7, ../sass/screen.scss */
body {
  padding: 40px;
}

/* line 10, ../sass/screen.scss */
p {
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* line 13, ../sass/screen.scss */
table.table {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
/* line 14, ../sass/screen.scss */
table.table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* line 19, ../sass/screen.scss */
table.table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #ECE7E7;
}
/* line 29, ../sass/screen.scss */
table.table .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove-circle {
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* line 38, ../sass/screen.scss */
form .list-inline > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
/* line 45, ../sass/screen.scss */
form .input-group label {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
/* line 47, ../sass/screen.scss */
form .input-group label input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/* line 54, ../sass/screen.scss */
.glyphicon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* line 58, ../sass/screen.scss */
.error {
  color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="formList">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Day 7 Angular Workaround</title>
  <link href="css/styles.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular-messages.js"></script>


 
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">


    <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customerModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Add Customer</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="customerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add/Search Customer</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="form" name="form" novalidate>

              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <h3>Customer Details</h3>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mobile">Mobile Number</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">+91</span><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.mobile"  placeholder="Enter phone Number..." ng-blur="mobileValidator(user)"/>
                    </div>
                  <!-- <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.mobile.$touched"> -->
                      <span ng-show="mobileValid" class="error">Enter valid mobile no</span>
                  <!-- </div> -->
                     <!-- <span>Mobile valid = {{form.input.$valid}}</span> -->
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name(Optional)</label>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                      <li><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.firstName" placeholder="First name" /></li>
                      <li><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.lastName" placeholder="Last name" /></li>
                    </ul>
                     
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="email">Email(optional)</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" ng-blur="emailValidator(user)" placeholder="Enter Email id here" />
                     <span ng-show="emailValid" class="error">Enter valid email</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
    
                    <label for="altMobile">Alternate contact No.(optional)</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">+91</span> <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.altMobile" ng-blur="altMobValidator(user)" placeholder="Enter Alternate Mobile here" />
                    </div>
                    <span class="error" ng-show="altMobileValid">Enter valid contact no.</span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="dob">Date Of birth(optional)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.dob" ng-blur="dobValidator(user)" />
                    <span class="error" ng-show="dobValid">Enter Valid Dob</span>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group" id="gender">

                    <label>Gender(optional)</label>
                   
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <label for="male"><input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" name="gender" value="male" />Male</label> 
                      <label for="female"><input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" name="gender" value="female" />Female</label>
                      <label for="others"><input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" name="gender" value="others" />Others</label>                      
                    </div>
 
                     
                  </div>
                 


              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h3>Residential Address</h3>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label>Pincode(optional)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pincode" ng-model="user.pincode" ng-blur="pincodeValidator(user)" placeholder="Enter Pincode" />
                    <span class="error" ng-show="pincodeValid">Enter Valid pincode.</span>
                </div>


               
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Address(optional)</label>
                    <textarea ng-model="user.address" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Enter address details"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="district">District(optional)</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.district" class="form-control" name="district" placeholder="Enter District here">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="district">State(optional)</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.state" class="form-control" name="state" placeholder="Enter State here">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="district">Country</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.country" class="form-control" value="india" name="country" placeholder="India(This service is only within India" disabled>
                </div>


              </div>
            
            </form> 
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addCustomer(user)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ng-hide="editUser"></span> Add Customer</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="updateCustomer(user)" ng-show="editUser">Update Customer</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
   
    <div id="showResults" ng-show="showResults" >
      <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Alternate Number</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Pincode</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>District</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        
      
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in formElements" class="active">

           <!--  <td ng-click="editing=true"><span>{{item.name}}</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ng-hide="editing"></span><input type="text" ng-model="item.name" ng-show="editing" ng-blur="editing=false" /></td> -->

             <td ng-repeat="td in item">
             <span>{{td}}</span>
             <!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ng-hide="editing"></span> -->
             <!-- <input type="text" ng-model="td" ng-show="editing" ng-blur="editing=false" /> -->
             </td>

           
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle action-btns" ng-click="delete(user, $index)"></span>
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customerModal" ng-click="edit()">Edit</button></td> 
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      
      
      </table>
    </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/final.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes in the modal window is immediately reflected in the table, you need to use the same object.

```
$scope.edit = function(us){
 $scope.editUser = true;
 $scope.user = us;}
```

And in html

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customerModal" ng-click="edit(item)">Edit</button>
```

Comment: I am reflecting it on update button click. Actually I went ahead and updated the result. But the problem is that it doesn't checks for null values so values shift their positions in the table. I updated my answer for update customer function.

Comment: Ok, you need define your model in `scope`, like: `$scope.user ={mobile:null,firstName:null};` and so on. In that case angular will copy that fields.