# Copy empty values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to copy the object via `angular.copy(object)`. But the problem is that it doesn't copy empty values. Is there any way to copy that too?

For now say I have a form which when edited for any field should update the object back to the table row in which I am reflecting the filled in object.

I am capturing the filled in values as `user` object. Yah `ng-model` being `user.name` , `user.phone` and so on. On clicking update button I am simply doing 
`$scope.formElements[index] = angular.copy(user);`

Now formElements array is formed when we add a record in a separate function.

So Angular's default behaviour is that it doesn't defines the key for empty values. So after copying my array gets shifted to left displaying only filled up values.

Any way to copy filled plus empty values when copying user object ?

full code is available at [Update form after editing any field value AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218124/update-form-after-editing-any-field-value-angularjs)

Comment: What if you do this instead : `angular.copy(user, $scope.formElements[index]);` ?

Comment: This does not work for me.  Still the same thing replicated

Answer (score 1):

Instate of copy you can use angular.toJson and JSON.parse method to duplicate "user" json.

so it will be look like this.

```
$scope.formElements[index] = angular.toJson(user);
$scope.formElements[index] = JSON.parse($scope.formElements[index]);
```

this will definitely help

Comment: Say I have 6 values and I leave 2 empty. The table data shows empty values below the empty heading. Desired behavior. Cool ! Let's edit the form by hitting edit button. Then the same form pops up by prefilled values. Then if I edit any field and hit update button. The values earlier shown empty are ignored and under say table heading of email something else shows up. 
This toJson unfortunately works the same way as copy would

Comment: Can You please add js fiddle or plunker so as to i can get it properly and then i can provide you a soluton.

Comment: I have found the solution to update. Basically I just stuck to building the new object manually on update and then assigned it to formElements[index]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you can do similar to this

```
$scope.formElements = [];

        $scope.update = function() {            
            $scope.formElements.push($scope.user);          
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="user" ng-model="user.name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="phone" ng-model="user.phone">
            <input type="submit" ng-click="update()">
```

**NOTE:**

This will create key for blank value also. But the problem is, for the first element it will give undefined if user object values are null.

That is expected behaviour, because for the very first time if you pass empty values Angular will not know what key it needs to create.

If you handle very first scenario then rest will work.

To handle define your model object inside controller

```
$scope.user = {
    name: '',
    phone: ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to define your `user model` like this in your `controller`

```
$scope.user = {
    name: '',
    phone: ''
}
```

There is no need of extra copying